# Why does querying date provides wrong output/result in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `uploaded_at` column in database having type as timestamp.

```php
$from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("-2 months"));
$data = Post::where('uploaded_at' , '>' , $from)->paginate(20);
```

This piece of code is giving all the data from the post table where I needed only the last 2 months post.

Comment: I guess you're using the wrong date format. Try `Y-m-d`.
Sorry, that's what Tushar already wrote below.

Comment: i tried that format in the beginning but it didn't work. i even checked if there was problem with the table using phpmyadmin by this query which gives me proper output...[ SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE uploaded_at > '2020-1-1' ]...

Comment: If the column type really is `TIMESTAMP`, I suppose you have to use `Y-m-d 00:00:00` including time information, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html#date-and-time-string-numeric-literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-2 months"));
$data = Post::whereDate('uploaded_at' , '>=' , $from)->paginate(20);
```

Comment: i tried but still the same...to check if my database table  had any problem i even checked using phpmyadmin which gave me proper results.query: [ SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uploaded_at > '2020-1-1' ]

Comment: i tried using your code showing 0 results. can it be because its in the localhost ...

Comment: Can you check last executed query, for check the query. query is ok or not

Comment: I mean can you check the query builder build which query. Is it create expected as your requirement?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: i fixed the problem ...query was not the problem it seems... my mysql was giving some problem..after i reinstalled xampp everything became normal.... thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a default package, named `Carbon` Which can easily handle do this, like this  :

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$previous = $date->subMonths(2);
$data =Post::whereBetween('uploaded_at', [$previous, $date])->paginate(20);
```

Don't forget to `use Carbon\Carbon;` on th top.

Hope this helps..

Comment: tried this but showing the same results as tushar's.

Comment: sorry there was no problem with the query....after installing xampp again it got fixed.... i think the problem was with my mysql ... thank you

Comment: and your answer worked for me too but i preferred tushars because it uses builtin php functions.... and whereBetween didn't work for me... This worked: $date = Carbon::now();
$previous = $date->subMonths(3);
$data = Post::where('uploaded_at' , '>' , $previous)->paginate(20);

Answer (score 0):

Use the `whereDate()` function to compare date:

```
$data = Post::whereDate('uploaded_at' , '>' , $from)->paginate(20);
```